# office Fabric ui people picker picks first value

Tags: spfx, office-ui-fabric

I am using office fabric UI Normal people picker and its working fine used in similar as what articles says but somehow it always select first value if tap through mouse and on using keyboard arrow down it work fine

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/peoplepicker

Please find below code

```
<NormalPeoplePicker
onChange={this._onChange.bind(this)}
onResolveSuggestions={this._onFilterChanged.bind(this)}
getTextFromItem={(persona: IPersonaProps) => persona.primaryText}
inputProps={{ placeholder: 'To...' }}
className={'ms-PeoplePicker'}
key={'normal'}
selectedItems={this.state.selectedItems}
/>

import { IBasePickerSuggestionsProps,
IBasePicker,
NormalPeoplePicker,
ValidationState,
IPersonaProps, Persona,
people, mru, Fabric } from 'office-ui-fabric-react';

selectedItems:any;

selectedItems:[],


_onChange(items: any[]) {
var assignees=[];
items.forEach(function(assignuser){
var assineedetails={};
assineedetails["AccountName"]=assignuser.AccountName;
assineedetails["UserProfile_GUID"]=assignuser.UserProfile_GUID;
assineedetails["imageUrl"]=assignuser.imageUrl;
assineedetails["primaryText"]=assignuser.primaryText;
assineedetails["secondaryText"]=assignuser.secondaryText;
assignees.push(assineedetails);
});
this.setState({selectedItems: assignees});

}

_onFilterChanged(filterText: string) {
var reactHandler = this;
if (filterText) {
if (filterText.length > 2) {
//return this._searchPeople(filterText, this._peopleList);
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
var getUserAPIURL = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/search/query?querytext='*" + filterText + "*'&trimduplicates=true&rowlimit=10&sourceid='b09a7990-05ea-4af9-81ef-edfab16c4e31'";
var digest = $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val();
$.ajax({
url: getUserAPIURL,
method: "GET",
async: true,
headers: {
"Accept": "application/json; odata=nometadata",
"X-RequestDigest": digest
},
success: function (data) {
var relevantResults = data.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults;
var resultCount = relevantResults.TotalRows;
var people = [];
if (resultCount > 0) {
relevantResults.Table.Rows.forEach(function (row) {
var persona = {};
row.Cells.forEach(function (cell) {
if (cell.Key === 'AccountName') {
persona["AccountName"] = cell.Value;
persona["imageUrl"] = reactHandler.getProfileDetails(cell.Value);
}
if (cell.Key === 'UserProfile_GUID')
persona["UserProfile_GUID"] = cell.Value;
if (cell.Key === 'WorkEmail')
persona["secondaryText"] = cell.Value;
if (cell.Key === 'PreferredName')
persona["primaryText"] = cell.Value;
});
people.push(persona);
});
}
resolve(people);
},
error: function (data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
reject(this._peopleList = []);
}
});

});
}
} else {
return [];
}
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code you are using to your question?

Comment: @GaneshSanap added the code